# Ionic dynamically show Tab Icons Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tabs

I hope you are well.

I have a struggle  and I don't know how to solve it ,if you have a bit of time I would appreciate some help.

I am trying to change the ion-icons dynamically in my tabs , so basically I have active svg and inactive svg of each icon.  I tried some things , but its not really working , can someone please give me a hint or tell me what should I do ?

Some code :

```
ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button
      [tab]="icons.name"
      class="sundayActivated"
      *ngFor=" let icons of tabsArray"
    >
      <ion-icon
        *ngIf="icons.name === sunday"
        [src]="icons.iconActive"
        (click)="toggleTabs()"
      ></ion-icon>
```

```
tabsArray = [
    {
      name: "sunday",
      iconActive: "./../../assets/icon/tabs/xactive.svg",
      iconInactive: "../../../assets/icon/tabs/xinactive.svg",
    },
    {
      name: "monday",
      iconActive: "../../../assets/icon/tabs/yinactive.svg",
      iconInactive: "../../../assets/icon/tabs/yactive.svg",
    },
  ];
```

```
 toggleTabs() {
    this.tabsArray.find((tab) => {
      if (tab.name === "sunday") {
        tab.iconActive = "../../../assets/icon/tabs/xactive.svg";
        tab.iconInactive = "../../../assets/icon/tabs/yinactive.svg";
      }

      if (tab.name === "monday") {
        tab.iconActive = "../../../assets/icon/tabs/yactive.svg";
        tab.iconActive = "../../../assets/icon/tabs/xinactive.svg";
      }
      console.log(tab);
    });
  }
```

I can see the icons with this code but when i change the tab the icons dont change. Can someone please help?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your *ngIf of your icons tag, where you are checking for string without any quote.

try the following instead.

```
<ion-icon
        *ngIf="icons.name === 'sunday'"
        [src]="icons.iconActive"
        (click)="toggleTabs()"
      ></ion-icon>
```